# Chamar uma variável SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho a variavel X

```
X = setInterval(function() {  ...
```

e depois de um tempo eu dei um stop nesse setInterval com a função `clearInterval(X)`

Como faço para chamar essa variável para ela continuar o loop depois de tê-la "apagado"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não podes parar e recomeçar um `setInterval`. O que podes fazer é:

- recomeçar se não houver dados que precisem ser re-utilizados
- simular *pausa* via retorno de dentro da função

### Primeiro caso:

Define a função fora do `setInterval` e depois começa/recomeça:

```
function beeper(){
    // fazer algo
}

var x = setInterval(beeper, 1000);

// para parar:
clearInterval(x);

// para recomeçar:
x = setInterval(beeper, 1000);
```

### Segudo caso

```
var semaforoVermelho = false;
function beeper(){
    if (semaforoVermelho) return;
    // fazer algo
}

setInterval(beeper, 1000);

// para pausar:
semaforoVermelho = true;

// para recomeçar:
semaforoVermelho = false;
```